How to calculate total machine power consumption at each time interval, keeping track of start and end times?
I have a dataset where multiple machines (A, B, C) are consuming power at different rates over specific time periods. The data includes start and end times of each machine's power usage and the power consumption rate. I want to compute the total power consumption at each time interval where there is a change, and track the start and end times of those periods.
How can I achieve this in R, while ensuring I correctly handle start and end times?
Example data:
data <- data.frame(
  MachineID = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  PowerA_Start = c("2022-01-01 00:00:00", "2022-01-01 02:00:00", "2022-01-02 00:00:00", "2022-01-02 02:00:00"),
  PowerA_End = c("2022-01-01 01:00:00", "2022-01-01 03:00:00", "2022-01-02 01:00:00", "2022-01-02 03:00:00"),
  PowerA_Consumption = c(5, 10, 7, 12),
  PowerB_Start = c("2022-01-01 00:30:00", "2022-01-01 02:30:00", "2022-01-02 00:30:00", "2022-01-02 02:30:00"),
  PowerB_End = c("2022-01-01 01:30:00", "2022-01-01 03:30:00", "2022-01-02 01:30:00", "2022-01-02 03:30:00"),
  PowerB_Consumption = c(3, 6, 5, 8),
  PowerC_Start = c("2022-01-01 01:00:00", "2022-01-01 03:00:00", "2022-01-02 01:00:00", "2022-01-02 03:00:00"),
  PowerC_End = c("2022-01-01 02:00:00", "2022-01-01 04:00:00", "2022-01-02 02:00:00", "2022-01-02 04:00:00"),
  PowerC_Consumption = c(4, 8, 6, 10)
)

Expected result:

For each machine, calculate the total power consumption at each time interval, and return the start and end times of those intervals where the power consumption changes.

           MachineID Start_Time          End_Time            Total_Consumption
           <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>                   <dbl>
     1         1 2022-01-01 00:00:00 2022-01-01 00:30:00          5
     2         1 2022-01-01 00:30:00 2022-01-01 01:00:00          8
     .
     .


Welcome to So.  For "expected result", we need to see the exact numerical values you expect, the columns you expect (and the values in each row of the data frame, if relevant), not just a written description.  How do MachineID values 1 and 2 correspond to A, B and C as suffices to Machine in your column names?

Thank you for the advice. I have changed names of values as "PowerA, B, C" and "Power*_Consumption" and added the Table of expected result. Hope this helps to understand what I want to do.

I suspect you are looking for tidyr::pivot_longer().

@Friede Definitely. But I want to combine the consumption for the same time period.

I do not see a problem. You are more likely to receive an answer if you include your attempt and explain where eerors/issues occur..

There are shorter ways to do this, but I think it's clearest to follow if we reshape longer twice, first to put the various "PowerA/PowerB/etc." observations into their own rows, and then to separate Starts and Ends. That's helpful since Start represents an increase in consumption, while End is a reduction.
Then we can track cumulative changes in consumption per machine, keep the last observation per machine-time, and just keep the columns we want in the end.
library(tidyverse)
data |>
  # pivot PowerA/PowerB/etc. into rows, then into Start/End
  pivot_longer(-MachineID,
               names_to = c("phase", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)") |>
  pivot_longer(Start:End, values_to = "dt") |>

  # arrange by time, track cumulative changes, and keep last row per machine/time
  arrange(MachineID, dt) |>
  mutate(Total_Consumption = cumsum(Consumption * ifelse(name == "End", -1, 1)),
         .by = MachineID) |>
  slice_max(name, by = c(MachineID, dt)) |>

  # final presentation
  mutate(MachineID, Start_time = dt, End_time = lead(dt), Total_Consumption,
        .keep = "none", .by = MachineID) |>
  filter(!is.na(End_time))

Result
# A tibble: 16 × 4
   MachineID Total_Consumption Start_time          End_time           
       <dbl>             <dbl> <chr>               <chr>              
 1         1                 5 2022-01-01 00:00:00 2022-01-01 00:30:00
 2         1                 8 2022-01-01 00:30:00 2022-01-01 01:00:00
 3         1                 7 2022-01-01 01:00:00 2022-01-01 01:30:00
 4         1                 4 2022-01-01 01:30:00 2022-01-01 02:00:00
 5         1                10 2022-01-01 02:00:00 2022-01-01 02:30:00
 6         1                16 2022-01-01 02:30:00 2022-01-01 03:00:00
 7         1                14 2022-01-01 03:00:00 2022-01-01 03:30:00
 8         1                 8 2022-01-01 03:30:00 2022-01-01 04:00:00
 9         2                 7 2022-01-02 00:00:00 2022-01-02 00:30:00
10         2                12 2022-01-02 00:30:00 2022-01-02 01:00:00
11         2                11 2022-01-02 01:00:00 2022-01-02 01:30:00
12         2                 6 2022-01-02 01:30:00 2022-01-02 02:00:00
13         2                12 2022-01-02 02:00:00 2022-01-02 02:30:00
14         2                20 2022-01-02 02:30:00 2022-01-02 03:00:00
15         2                18 2022-01-02 03:00:00 2022-01-02 03:30:00
16         2                10 2022-01-02 03:30:00 2022-01-02 04:00:00


The result is definitely correct. However, I received an error message: 'Problematic argument: by = c(MachineID, dt) in slice_max().' It seems that slice_max() does not have the argument .by = ....　Instead, I tried group_by(MachineID, dt)  before slice_max(name) and it worked. Could this be due to my environment?

by was added as a parameter for slice_* with dplyr 1.1.0 in Jan 2023. Perhaps you're using an earlier version? https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html. Confusingly, slice uses ".by" (like mutate/summarize/filter), but slice_head/slice_tail/slice_min/slice_max use "by".
